# Django comparing form field value with selected value

Tags: django-templates

I have a number of select box form fields which I need to output in the template with custom markup as a list. To do this I have created an include which gets passed the current form field as an argument.

I can loop over the list of options to create the list I want without any problems. My problem is that above the list of options I need to display either the form label, or the current selected value. This is the code I have to do this:

```html
{% if field.value %}
    {% for value, option in field.field.choices %}
        {% if value == field.value %}
            {{ option }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ field.label }}
{% endif %}
```

If for example `value` in the above code is 1, and `field.value` is also 1, the equality test doesn't work and the bit of code within the if statement does not get executed. I guessed it might be down to the data type of the two values I was comparing, so I tried casting both to an integer as follows:

```html
{% if field.value %}
    {% for value, option in field.field.choices %}
        {% if value|add:"0" == field.value|add:"0" %}
            {{ option }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ field.label }}
{% endif %}
```

This worked fine for the case where the values in the select box were integers. However, sometimes my select boxes have booleans as the value, so in this case the comparison won't work with the integer casting applied.

How can I safely compare the two values whatever the type of data is being compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer.

The issue is that the selected value is always a string, and the value in the forloop could be an integer or a boolean (or potentially other data types). The answer is to cast the value in the forloop to a string:

```
{% if field.value %}
    {% for value, option in field.field.choices %}
        {% if value|stringformat:"s" == field.value %}
            {{ option }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ field.label }}
{% endif %}
```